# How can I program a file transfer system using UDP so that files are transferred instead of messages?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pid;
int sock;

void interrupt(int sig) {
    close(sock);
    if (pid) {
        kill(pid, sig);
        printf("Exiting...\n");
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s portnumber\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    signal(SIGINT, &interrupt);
    signal(SIGTERM, &interrupt);

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in addr = {
        AF_INET,
        htons(atoi(argv[1])),
        INADDR_ANY
    };

    int res = bind( sock,
                    (struct sockaddr*)&addr,
                    sizeof(addr));
    
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("Bind");
        return -1;
    }

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid) {
        while(1) {
            char buf[100];
            int chars = 0;
            char c;
            int portnumber;

            scanf("%d", &portnumber);

            struct sockaddr_in target = {
                AF_INET,
                htons(portnumber),
                inet_addr("127.0.01")
            };

            while(read(0, &c, 1) > 0) {
                if(c == '\n') {
                    // TODO send buf
                    sendto(sock, buf, chars, 0,
                        (struct sockaddr*)&target,
                        sizeof(target));
                    chars = 0;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (chars < 100)
                        buf[chars++] = c;
                    else
                        printf("\n->Maximum character is reached, press enter to send\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        struct sockaddr_in incoming;
        int lenincoming = sizeof(incoming);

        char buf[101];
        int chars = 0;

        while(  (chars = recvfrom(sock, &buf, 100, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*)&incoming,
                &lenincoming)) >= 0)
        {
            write(1, buf, chars);
            write(1, "\n", 1);

            buf[chars] = 0;

            if (strcmp(buf, "ok") != 0) {
                sendto( sock, "ok", 2, 0,
                        (struct sockaddr*)&incoming,
                        lenincoming);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to modify this program so that a file can be sent. It should ask a port number and filename and then send the file in 100 byte packages to the other side. Every package should have starting point of the data. When I get data, I should seek to the location that is specified at the start of the data. Save to fixed filename or if you want transfer filename first. You can assume that you are working on the same system.

I read about "lseek(fd, start, SEEK_SET)". I think it should help. But how to combine it all?

Comment: You need to send not just the file contents but also the file offset of each chunk. The task description even gives you that hint explicitly - "*Every package should have starting point of the data*". Then when  you receive the packet you should get the offset, lseek to that point and then write the data.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that

Comment: Don't forget, of course, that you'll need to keep track of each chunk and reassemble them in the right order. There's no delivery guarantees on UDP packets.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that

Comment: Read up on TFTP for ideas.